# drupal 7 - Create a custom block and assign a tpl to it

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, themes, block

I have created a custom block and would like to associate it with a tpl in the **associated module**.

Currently I can associate only a tpl file in the **theme folder**.

I would like it to be a tpl of the module and then use the hook_menu and pass some data to it, which is impossible (to my knowledge) with a tpl in the theme folder.

Is that even possible?

If this is not possible I would like to use the tpl in my theme as a container and use the hook_menu to pass its contents but I don't know how to return the tpl/theme I will create in the module.

Can someone help me?

Answer (score 1):

I hope the below example helps you

```
function MYMODULEBLOCK_block_info() {
  $blocks['MYMODULE_BLOCK_NAME'] = array(
    'info' => t('MYMODULE BLOCK TITLE'), 
    'cache' => DRUPAL_NO_CACHE, //there are a number of caching options for this
  );

  return $blocks;
}

function MYMODULEBLOCK_block_view($delta = ''){
  switch($delta){
    case 'MYMODULE_BLOCK_NAME':
      if(user_access('access content')){ //good idea to check user perms here
         $block['subject'] = t('MYBLOCK_TITLE');
         $block['content'] = MYMODULE_BLOCK_FUNCTION_ITEMS();
         return $block;
      }
      break;
  }
}

function MYMODULE_BLOCK_FUNCTION_ITEMS(){
  $items = array();
  $items['VAR_ONE'] = array('#markup' => 'VAR_ONE_OUTPUT'); //this is the simplest kind of render array
  $items['VAR_TWO'] = array(
                        '#prefix' => '<div>',
                        '#markup' => 'VAR_TWO_OUTPUT',
                            '#suffix' => '</div>',
                          );
// this is where the $items get sent to your default MYMODULE_BLOCK.tpl.php that gets 
// registered below
      return theme('MYMODULE_BLOCK_FUNCTION_ITEMS', array('items' => $items)); 
    }

//here you are registering your default tpl for the above block 
function MYMODULE_theme() {   
  $module_path = drupal_get_path('module', 'MYMODULE');
  $base = array(
    'path' => "$module_path/theme",   
  );
  return array(
    'MYMODULE_BLOCK_FUNCTION_ITEMS' => $base + array(
      'template' => 'MYMODULE_BLOCK',  //leave off .tpl.php
      'variables' => array('items' => NULL,),
    ),   
  ); 
}
```

All the stuff in CAPITALS (except DRUPAL_NO_CACHE) can be named whatever you want

And then in a subfolder in your module called theme/ there should be a file called MYMODULE_BLOCK.tpl.php which could have this in it:

```
<?php 

$items = $variables['items'];

print render($items['VAR_ONE']); 
print render($items['VAR_TWO']);
```

And if you wanted to, you could actually overwrite the "default" module implementation you just made for MYMODULE_BLOCK.tpl.php in your theme as you wish in block--MYMODULE--DELTA.tpl.php

Answer (score 0):

The way I do this is as follows...

```
function YOURMODULE_menu(){
    $items['somepage'/%] = array(
        'title' => 'Some page title',
        'page callback' => 'YOURMODULE_page',
        'page arguments' => array(1),
        'type' => MENU_CALLBACK,
        'access arguments' => array('access content'),
    );
    return $items;
}

function YOURMODULE_page($data){
    $output = 'value from YOURMODULE module! = '.$data;
    return theme('theme_file',array('results' => $output));
}

function YOURMODULE_theme() {
    $path = drupal_get_path('module', 'YOURMODULE');
    return array(
        'theme_file' => array(
            'variables' => array('results' => null),
            'template' => 'theme_file',
            'path' => $path, 
        ),
    );
}
```

Place your tpl file theme_file.tpl.php in your module directory and inside it use the below code.

```
<?php print $results; ?>
```

or

```
function YOURMODULE_theme() {
    return array(
        'theme_file' => array(
            'variables' => array('results' => null),
            'template' => 'theme_file',
        ),
    );
}
```

Place your tpl file theme_file.tpl.php in your theme directory and inside it place the below code

```
<?php print $results; ?>
```

Go to your http://yourdomain.com/somepage/somedata to see the result.